# How to import a Typescript Vue project into Javascript Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, npm, vue-component

I want to use [this](https://github.com/lbgm/vue-pro-calendar) Calendar component into my Javascript Vue 3 project. To do so, I created a component in my project called ProCalendar.vue, and copy-paste the App.vue code that shows in the example. And I add the dependency in the main.js file.

Once having this setup, it gives my the following errors when I try to do a `npm run dev`:

```
INFO  Starting development server...


 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                                                  19:54:20

[eslint]
C:\Users\chuan\Documents\GitHub\PraePlan\services\frontend\src\main_components\home_components\ProCalendar.vue
  3:19  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (3:19)

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
 error  in ./src/main_components/home_components/ProCalendar.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=ts

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:19)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { defineComponent as _defineComponent } from 'vue'
| import "vue-pro-calendar/style";
> import { ref, type Ref } from "vue";
| import type { Configs, Appointment } from "vue-pro-calendar";
|

 error  in ./src/main_components/home_components/ProCalendar.vue?vue&type=template&id=d18ce454&ts=true        

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:27)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { createCommentVNode as _createCommentVNode, resolveComponent as _resolveComponent, createVNode as _createVNode, Fragment as _Fragment, openBlock as _openBlock, createElementBlock as _createElementBlock } from "vue"
|
> export function render(_ctx: any,_cache: any,$props: any,$setup: any,$data: any,$options: any) {
|   const _component_pro_calendar = _resolveComponent("pro-calendar", true)!
|

ERROR in ./src/main_components/home_components/ProCalendar.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=ts (./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/main_components/home_components/ProCalendar.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=ts) 3:19      
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:19)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { defineComponent as _defineComponent } from 'vue'
| import "vue-pro-calendar/style";
> import { ref, type Ref } from "vue";
| import type { Configs, Appointment } from "vue-pro-calendar";
|
 @ ./src/main_components/home_components/ProCalendar.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=ts 1:0-147 1:0-147 1:148-284 1:148-284  
 @ ./src/main_components/home_components/ProCalendar.vue 2:0-73 3:0-68 3:0-68 6:49-55
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/main_components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 2:0-60 33:4-15
 @ ./src/main_components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 1:0-196 1:0-196 1:197-382 1:197-382
 @ ./src/main_components/Home.vue 2:0-55 3:0-50 3:0-50 6:49-55
 @ ./src/router/index.js 2:0-42 27:13-17
 @ ./src/main.js 3:0-30 6:30-36

ERROR in ./src/main_components/home_components/ProCalendar.vue?vue&type=template&id=d18ce454&ts=true (./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/main_components/home_components/ProCalendar.vue?vue&type=template&id=d18ce454&ts=true) 3:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:27)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { createCommentVNode as _createCommentVNode, resolveComponent as _resolveComponent, createVNode as _createVNode, Fragment as _Fragment, openBlock as _openBlock, createElementBlock as _createElementBlock } from "vue"
|
> export function render(_ctx: any,_cache: any,$props: any,$setup: any,$data: any,$options: any) {
|   const _component_pro_calendar = _resolveComponent("pro-calendar", true)!
|
 @ ./src/main_components/home_components/ProCalendar.vue?vue&type=template&id=d18ce454&ts=true 1:0-216 1:0-216
 @ ./src/main_components/home_components/ProCalendar.vue 1:0-80 6:68-74 16:79-18:3 17:29-35 16:2-18:4
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/main_components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 2:0-60 33:4-15
 @ ./src/main_components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 1:0-196 1:0-196 1:197-382 1:197-382
 @ ./src/main_components/Home.vue 2:0-55 3:0-50 3:0-50 6:49-55
 @ ./src/router/index.js 2:0-42 27:13-17
 @ ./src/main.js 3:0-30 6:30-36

ERROR in [eslint]
C:\Users\chuan\Documents\GitHub\PraePlan\services\frontend\src\main_components\home_components\ProCalendar.vue
  3:19  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (3:19)

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


webpack compiled with 3 errors
```

I googled about it and found that a possible problem could be that I didn't had installed typescript in my projecct, so I runed `npm install typescript` and `npm install ts-loader` and didn't changed nothing.

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "praeplan",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "serve": "serve -s dist -p 8080",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-calendar-3": "^2.2.6",
    "vue-pro-calendar": "^1.1.6",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "cypress": "^9.7.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.2",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.8",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "gitHooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  }
}
```

My ProCalendar.vue file (copy-pasted from the github project):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import "vue-pro-calendar/style";
import { ref, type Ref } from "vue";
import type { Configs, Appointment } from "vue-pro-calendar";

const cfg = ref<Configs>({
  viewEvent: undefined,
  reportEvent: {
    icon: true,
    text: "",
  },
  searchPlaceholder: "",
  eventName: "",
  closeText: "",
  nativeDatepicker: true,
});

const evts: Ref<Appointment[]> = ref([
  {
    date: "2022-11-19T14:00:00.000Z",
    comment: "",
    id: "cl32rbkjk1700101o53e3e3uhn",
    keywords: "Projet BAMBA",
    name: "MONTCHO Kévin",
  },
  //...
]);

</script>

<template>
<!-- all props are optional -->
<pro-calendar
  :events="evts"
  :loading="false"
  :config="cfg"
  view="month"
  date="2022-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
  @calendarClosed="void 0"
  @fetchEvents="void 0"
/>
</template>
```

And my `main.js` file:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import { ProCalendar } from "vue-pro-calendar" 

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).use(ProCalendar).mount("#app");
```

Thanks for your help! :P

Comment: Any proper lib written in TS is supposed to work both in JS and TS projects. You shouldn't add TS to your own project because of that, this will just result in problems with a setup you didn't previously test. Just remove all TS types from ProCalendar.vue and make it valid JS

Comment: Huh, make sense. I just found out that TS is an extension of JS. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estus Flask in his comment has the right of it.  You don't need to install TS if you remove all TS related code. Your script should look like this:

```js
<script setup>
import "vue-pro-calendar/style";
import { ref } from "vue";

const cfg = ref({
  viewEvent: undefined,
  reportEvent: {
    icon: true,
    text: "",
  },
  searchPlaceholder: "",
  eventName: "",
  closeText: "",
  nativeDatepicker: true,
});

const evts = ref([
  {
    date: "2022-11-19T14:00:00.000Z",
    comment: "",
    id: "cl32rbkjk1700101o53e3e3uhn",
    keywords: "Projet BAMBA",
    name: "MONTCHO Kévin",
  },
  //...
]);
</script>
```

I tested and confirmed myself in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-gxxvhu?file=src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev) that the lib works as a JS lib